# Exporting plugin from Eclipse, how can I test it?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, export

If I export a plugin from Eclipse using the 'Export -> Deployable Plug-ins and Fragments' as a jar file. I was wondering how I can then use this plugin in my workspace after I restart Eclipse. Are there any additional steps I need to perform to use the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the JAR in a folder named dropins/eclipse/plugins under your target eclipse directory.

An easier method to install it is to select 'install into host' when you export the plugin.

For testing purposes you shouldn't have to use the dropins folder, but instead launch it as an eclipse plugin.

Depending on the type of plugin you have created you may need to click a button or hotkey to activate it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm not going to launch it as an eclipse plugin for testing purposes as the eclipse instance that is launched seems to crash with a message that I can't remember off the top of my head. Notwithstanding, I'll try out the aforementioned approach.

Comment: Do I export the plugin as a jar file or a runnable jar file?

Comment: Do export > deployable plugins and fragments > into directory

Comment: BTW if it crashes when launching as an eclipse plugin you should try to raise the memory limit in eclipse and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Just copy it into the dropins folder of Eclipse. *Do not* use the plugins folder directly as there is a good chance it won't be picked up.

Comment: Yes, it should start by default when Eclipse is run. I think there are options in plugin.xml to control this though. You do understand I mean the eclipse home directory and *not* your workspace though?

Comment: Spot on. It starts when I load up eclipse alright. Yep, I was referring to the eclipse home directory, not my workspace folder. Thanks for your help.